# Getting resource files when executing custom maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have my custom maven plugin, which has to run tests programmatically on a test phase for example. So I have something like that

```
@Mojo(name = "aggregate", requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.RUNTIME)
public class AcceptanceTestMojo extends AbstractMojo {

  @Override
  public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    TestExecutor testExecutor = new TestExecutor();
    testExecutor.setTestClasses(new Class[]{TestClass.class});
    testExecutor.run();
  }

}
```

So the problem comes because the TestClass.class is from another maven module and actually the resources which I want to get are loaded in that module classpath. In that TestClass I have the following method:

```
public Object[][] retrieveFile() throws IOException {
    String[] issuesKeys = IOUtils.toString(
        Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fileName"))
    .split("\\n");
    ....
    ....
  }
```

If I build the module where the TestClass belongs to everything is working fine, because Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() is loading the correct ClassLoader, but if run it with my plugin as I run the test programatically Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() is loading the classpath of my plugin, so the file I want to retrive is not there and a RuntimeException is thrown.

So my question is how to get the correct ClassLoader so that to be able to get the file or is there a way to load files in classpath  manually with java?

Comment: Why are using a custom plugin insteaf of the existing plugins? What kind special case you like to cover which is not covered by the existing plugins?

Comment: I have to implement one specific framework and I need to do it with maven plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution- I modified the currentThread ClassLoader- I got all required classes from the classpath of the maven project I am executing the plugin on. This is possible with injecting the MavenProject bean:

```
@Component
private MavenProject project;
```